# python insert into sql error

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-2.7, insert-into

I'm getting an SQL error in the following python code when I try to insert some values collected in the python code into my database via SQL. I'm getting an SQL error on the code highlighted in BOLD. Any help appreciated!

```
def add_ingredients(cursor) :
    while True:
      ingredient = raw_input("Name of ingredient (q to quit):")
      if ingredient.lower() !='q':
          num = raw_input("Number in storage: ")
          description = raw_input("description: ")
          sql = '''insert into ingredients 
             (title, amount, description)
            values
             **(:title, :amount, :description)'''**
          cursor.execute(sql,
           {"title":ingredient, "amount":num, "description":description})
          print "Added!"
      else:
          print "Okay, quitting."
          break
```

Comment: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':title, :amount,'':description)' at line 4

Comment: You should have stated that in the question, as well as naming the library you are using to connect. But what gave you the idea that it accepts named parameters in that format?

Comment: Please get rid of the attempt to bold the erroneous part of the query and show your query as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Connector does not expect named parameters like that. As [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) shows, you should use the `%(var_name)s` format for dictionary interpolation:

```
 sql = '''insert into ingredients (title, amount, description)
          values (%(title)s, %(amount)s, %(description)s)'''
  cursor.execute(sql, {"title": ingredient, "amount": num, "description": description})
```

Comment: what would be the problem if we use `sql = '''insert into ingredients (title, amount, description) values ({title}, {amount}, {description})'''
sql = sql.format({"title":ingredient, "amount":num, "description":description})
cursor.execute(sql)
 ` as you downvoted my answer wanted to know.

Comment: That exposes you to SQL injection. There's a reason why the db API supports parameters.